# Error en la instalacion del ejecutable de Fly.io

Tags: powershell, instalacion

Quizás mi pregunta sea muy básica, pero quiero utilizar Fly.io (estoy haciendo la segunda parte de Argentina programa y me lo sugieren para la creación del portfolio) y al utilizar el comando "iwr https://fly.io/install.ps1 -useb | iex" en el powershell me tira el error de "iwr" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable."
Probé correrlo desde el powershell, desde vscode, desde todos los lugares que se me ocurrió, pero no logre hacer la instalación.
Busque en la ayuda de la pagina y no encontré nada que me oriente. Alguien sabrá decirme que puedo probar o modificar para poder ejecutarlo? o sugerirme algún remplazo?

Desde ya, muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimado Rondano, encantando de encontrar a alguien que esta atravesando el mismo problema que yo. La solucion que encontre fue la siguiente:

En el cmd de windows ejecutar el siguiente comando:

*msiexec.exe /package PowerShell-7.3.0-win-x64.msi /quiet ADD_EXPLORER_CONTEXT_MENU_OPENPOWERSHELL=1 ADD_FILE_CONTEXT_MENU_RUNPOWERSHELL=1 ENABLE_PSREMOTING=1 REGISTER_MANIFEST=1 USE_MU=1 ENABLE_MU=1 ADD_PATH=1*

Esto te va a instalar la ultima version de Windows Powershell.

A continuacion ejecutas, en el mismo cmd, la sentencia de Fly.io:

*iwr https://fly.io/install.ps1 -useb | iex*

De esta forma pude instalar Fly.io en el sistema para subir el backend.

Comment: Daniel! Muchisimas gracias!!!
Actualice el powershell y pude avanzar correctamente con todo!
Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Hola @DarianHiebl y Gradivat, como estan? como hicieron con fly.io, estoy haciendo también Argentina Programa y me encuentro con en fly te piden tarjeta,como lo solucionaron ustedes?añadiendo una tarjeta?

Comment: Hola Masterweed! Sisi, tuve que cargar los datos dei tarjeta para poder seguir... Además tuve que volver a usar JDK11 con NetBeans 11 porque tenía errores a la hora de la subir la imagen